# Kali Linux doesn't install

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux, dvd

I have a problem with Kali Linux. I want to install it with live DVD, so I burned DVD, and also booted it in BIOS, but when the install options shows (install, Live amd64, Live forensic mode and so on) I just block... I also tried with VMWare and VirtualBox but it still doesn't work.

Graphic memory - 256 MB
RAM - 4GB
64-bit
Intel 82945G Express Chipset Family

What else should I write here...

I would be grateful for any solution :)

Comment: I assume we need to know your VM settings. Me myself set up Kali sometime ago in VirtualBox without any problems.

Comment: What do you wanna know about VM? I don't get it. I actually on VM got problem with vt-x error, and same error on virtualbox

Comment: I realize I misread the question. First of all have you verified the image you burned on DVD? Next I would check, whether your hardware is supported by Kali or Debian at all. Regarding the vt-x error, have you enabled or disabled vt-x in BIOS?

Comment: My hardware support Debian, but I don't have option in BIOS for disabled/enabled vt-x

Comment: When I tried with Virtualbox it said: This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

Comment: This looks like VirtualBox thinks you have a 32bit CPU. What is your Host OS? Also are you sure you have a 64bit CPU? Also check whether you chose Debian (64-bit) for the VM in Virtualbox. If not you need create a new VM with that setting.

Comment: I am pretty sure, how to create that new VM?

Comment: Sorry? I don't get what you are saying.

Comment: Actually I realized that i don't have Debian/Linux 64-bit as a options when I want install, I got 32-bit altough I have Kali 64-bit, if you know what I want to say.

Comment: I got both kali and virtualbox 64-bit, but when I want to install kali, virtualbox offer me only 32-bit Debian..

Comment: Then VirtualBox doesn't recognize your 64bit CPU. I am not sure where this problem comes from although it had it some time ago. Which OS are you using currently to run VirtualBox?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Before we go off-topic: What do you want to archive eventually? A running Kali in a VM or on the hardware? Because we are facing two separate problems I assume.

Comment: I tried both, but I can't fix it... Now it doesn't matter is it VM or hardware, I need it to work anyway.

Comment: Okay, please update your question with the new information we uncovered already. Then look for a solution to the issue that VirtualBox doesn't recognize your 64bit CPU and then we can go ahead.

Comment: @JosipMareljić When you say **I block** do you mean you don't know how to answer the question, or that the computer stops responding?

Comment: Computer stops responding

Answer (score 0):

We are facing two issue in one question so I will  address them one by one:

**Virtual Machine**

As [this](https://superuser.com/questions/680051/virtualbox-not-recognizing-64-bit-cpu) superuser question suggests, try to solve the problem with VirtualBox not recognizing your 64bit CPU. After you are able to create a 64bit VM Kali should install without problems.

**Hardware Installation**

To answer this question we need further information. I will update the answer once we have more data on this.

Comment: Thnx for help. 

Also, I tried backtrack 5 r3 on VM, a there was vt-x error, and can't fix it, and tried in bios enabled virtualization, can't found it or just don't exist, and can't fin hyper-v in turn 'windows on or off' section

Comment: Then your CPU probably does not support VT-x. Check what CPU you have and look on Intel's homepage whether it supports VT-x at all.

Comment: Thx for helping.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer was helpful somehow at least I highly appreciate an upvote ;) And keep us updated so I can improve the answer and we can help others too. If you have more information on the hardware installation issues tell me, maybe we can work out a solution for that.